# Cannot pass authentication sending ajax request to mailgun

Tags: ajax, middleman, mailgun

I can do this:

```
curl --user 'api:MYAPIKEY' -F from=foo@bar.it -F to=MYEMAIL@gmail.com -F subject='foo' -F text='bar' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox93d8299f673a4c3295b7592956cb3d9.mailgun.org/messages
```

but I get a login popup when I try to do the same request with jquery .ajax() method:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic api:key-b50a9065a7b9bdf464f3d7a418ca96bb"},
    // url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
    url: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox93d8299f673a4c32952b7592956cb3d9.mailgun.org/messages",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        message: message
    },
    // cache: false,
    success: function() {
        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('problems');
    }
}
```

[image]

The server respond with a 401. any idea why?

thank you

Comment: There’s a detailed answer for this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076659/mailgun-api-request-header-field-authorization-is-not-allowed-by-access-control/50081948#50081948

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `username` and `password` fields

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox93d8299f673a4c32952b7592956cb3d9.mailgun.org/messages",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    username:'api',
    password: 'key-b50a9065a7b9bdf464f3d7a418ca96bb',
    ...
```

If you're setting the header yourself you have to base64 encode it

```
headers: {"Authorization": "Basic "+btoa("api:key-b50a9065a7b9bdf464f3d7a418ca96bb")},
```

Comment: Great! I wonder why [official docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html) have examples for many langs but not for Javascript.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @masciugo how did you overcome the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` or `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` limitations?

Comment: @cYrus Were you able to solve the Access-Control-Allow-Origin or Access-Control-Allow-Headers limitation ?

Comment: @user3457759 Now I can't remember all the details but I ended up using this in a Chrome extension with no problems; I assume checks are not so strict there. MailGun clearly doesn't want to support JavaScript as that would require to publicly expose the secret API key.

Comment: @cYrus Yes I think they just don't allow you to use JS. Forcing you to create at least a little backend to handle this.