# Mailgun API: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, cors, mailgun

How do I set up my .htaccess on my AngularJS application to prevent the following error message:

> Failed to load `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/example.com/messages`:
>   Request header field Authorization is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html
</IfModule>
```

I am getting the error message on my website [here](http://marquesslondon.com/contact), whenever the user tries to submit the contact form.

This is my code for the process:

```
function send(apiUrl, from, to, subject, body, apiKey) {
  var url = apiUrl;
  var dataJSON = {
    from: from,
    to: to,
    subject: subject,
    text: body,
    multipart: true
  };

  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + $base64.encode('api:'+apiKey)
    },
    transformRequest: function (obj) {
      var str = [];
      for (var p in obj) {
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      }
      return str.join('&');
    },
    data: dataJSON
  };

  $http(req).then(function (data) {
    if(data.data) {
      if(data.data.message === 'Queued. Thank you.') {
        $window.alert('Sent. Thank you.');
      }
      else {
        $window.alert(data.data.message);
      }
    }
    else {
      $window.alert('An error has occured. Please try again.');
    }
  }, function (data) {
    if(data.data) {
      if(data.data.message === 'Queued. Thank you.') {
        $window.alert('Sent. Thank you.');
      }
      else {
        $window.alert(data.data.message);
      }        }
    else {
      $window.alert('An error has occured. Please try again.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Usually this is set on the server code, not on .htaccess, but threre is no information about the backend.

Comment: I am using a Godaddy Wordpress hosting package

Comment: have you taken a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727306/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr

Comment: Usually an Apache / nginx config issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can’t make authenticated requests to the Mailgun API from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser. The Mailgun API intentionally doesn’t support that, [per their own documentation](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-js#mailgunjs-):

> NOTE: If used in the browser, a proxy is required to communicate with the Mailgun api due to cors limitations. Also, do not publish your private api key in frontend code.

Specifically, for requests from frontend JavaScript code running in browsers, the Mailgun API doesn’t allow the `Authorization` request header. You can verify that with `curl` or such:

```
$ curl -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: https://marquesslondon.com" \
       -i https://api.mailgun.net/v3/marquesslondon.com/messages

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
```

Notice the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header that endpoint returns doesn’t include `Authorization`. That means browsers will block your frontend JavaScript code from sending that API endpoint any request that includes the `Authorization` request header.

As far as your changes to the `.htaccess` file for the `http://marquesslondon.com` site, those are unnecessary and irrelevant; it it doesn’t matter what CORS headers you return from that (your) site, because it’s just the site initiating the request — you’re not sending any requests *to* it cross-origin.

Instead what matters are the CORS headers returned by the site you are actually sending a request to cross-origin, which is `https://api.mailgun.net`. And as explained above, that site returns a CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header which tells browsers not to allow requests that include the `Authorization` header — and that’s what results in you seeing the *Request header field Authorization is not allowed* error message cited in the question.