# Use MailGun API from react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, mailgun, fetch-api

I'm building a small react native app with Expo and needs a functionality to send e-mails from within the app. The user doesn't need to compose anything in the first place, so it's simply a matter of pushing a button that sends an e-mail to an address that the user types in.

My question is what the best architecture for this job is. So far I have looked into simply using the [Fetch API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) and then calling the MailGun API. However, as far as I understand it's not best practice to expose the API key in plain text, so I have considered [Cloud Functions from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?authuser=1), but am not sure whether this would be a viable option. Can anyone help me by pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: Use cloud functions, setup a listener on a key `.onCreate`. Then when the record is created in the react app - after the button is pressed, the cloud function can fire up and send the email.

Comment: As far as using the Fetch API, it wouldn’t work anyway because you can’t make authenticated requests to the Mailgun API from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser. The Mailgun API intentionally doesn’t support that. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076659/mailgun-api-request-header-field-authorization-is-not-allowed-by-access-control/50081948#50081948

Comment: Thanks @sketchthat, that worked for me. If you'll write into an answer, I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, it's not best practice to expose the API key as others could access it and use your MailGun credit.

An easy way to get started is to create a Cloud Function that listens to some path `.onCreate`.

Within your application - push to that path and the Cloud Function will fire up and send the mail without exposing your private key.

Something to note - you cannot connect to external domains while on the firebase free tier - so if you get an error over the API it could be because you need to update plans.

Comment: what do you mean by cannot connect to external domains?

Comment: On the Free Tier of Firebase you can only connect to Google services. Because MailGun is an external service you need to have a paid plan active for the cloud function to work.